# Plot .gnu file with gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have a file with .gnu extension.It contains gnuplot commands. I want to show up the graph, using gnuplot. So, which command is right for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run gnuplot directly with

```
gnuplot
```

The environment opens in the console and you can add your commands after `gnuplot>`

```
load 'file.gnu'
```

If you're not in the same directory, you have to go there before or specify the path for the file.

You can have a look at [this](http://physicspmb.ukzn.ac.za/index.php/Gnuplot_tutorial) tutorial and [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/) are some examples.

Comment: i still don't get a graph window show up

Comment: @computerSPro : show the content of the file

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a file  somefile.gnu

```
gnuplot -p somefile.gnu  > /tmp/sss.pdf
```

now just view your new pdf file

```
open /tmp/sss.pdf
```